# How to show a layout if there is no data in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am facing problem to show recyclerview list as empty. After checking many solutions in stackoverflow but issue is not resolved.  I am not able to show in activity as No records found when recycycler view is empty. please check my code where I did wrong in programming. Please check and revert me as soon as possible with proper solution for the same.

```
//here is my code 


if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

             gtr = data.getStringExtra ("obj");

                final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

                //Displaying Progressbar
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest (Request.Method.POST, url1, new Response.Listener <String> ( ) {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        Log.i (TAG, response.toString ( ));

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject (response);
                            dataList.clear ( );
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray ("documents");
                            for (int p = 0; p < jsonArray.length ( ); p++) {
                                JSONObject feedobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject (p);
                                //list.add (feedobj.getString ("documenttype"));
                                Document_model dataSet = new Document_model (feedobj.getString ("documenttypename"), feedobj.getString ("documentfilepath"), feedobj.getString ("documenttype"));
                                dataList.add (dataSet);
                            }


//Here I have defined empty visibility logic

                            if (!dataList.isEmpty ( )) {
                                //if data is available, don't show the empty text
                                Empty_View.setVisibility (View.INVISIBLE);
                                progressBar.setVisibility (View.GONE);
                                adapter = new Document_adapter (dataList, getApplicationContext ( ));
                                documentListView.setAdapter (adapter);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ( );

                            } else {
                                Empty_View.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
                        }





                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace ( );
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener ( ) {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }) {

                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map <String,String> map = new HashMap<> ();
                        map.put ("extraInfoId",gtr);
                        return map;
                    }
                };

                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue (AdditionalActivity.this);
                requestQueue.add (stringRequest);
                }
            } else if (resultCode == 0) {
                System.out.println("RESULT CANCELLED");
            }
```

Comment: what you want to show , if data is not available ?

Comment: Abhishek I want to show No record found if data is not available

Answer (score 0):

Reference of my code, If data is not available in `recyclerview` then i am showing a layout :

If pojo is not empty then it will call `RecyclerViewAdapter` `constructor` otherwise it will show include layout which is by default `visibility="gone"`.

```
 //No_data_found
    LinearLayout noDataFound;
    TextView noDataTv,noDataMsg;
    ImageView noDataImg;
    Button goBackBtn;


        noDataFound = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.noDataFound);
        noDataTv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.noDataFoundTxt);
        noDataMsg = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.nosmallMessage);
        noDataImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageNoFound);
        goBackBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnBack);



                               if(code.equals("1")){
                                           // utils.showtoast("i m here");

                                            Gson gson = new Gson();

                                            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<InboundDatePojo>>() {}.getType();
                                            List<InboundDatePojo> mList = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), listType);


                                            if(mList.get(0).getResult()!=null){
                                                adapter = new InboundAdapter(getActivity(),mList.get(0).getResult());
                                                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                            }else{
                                               // utils.showtoast("No Data Found");
                                                noDataFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                noDataTv.setText("No Record Found");
                                                noDataMsg.setText("No inbound available for "+ bundle.getString("DATE"));

                                                goBackBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                                        getActivity().finish();
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
```

As per your code change according to my code : Empty_View set it visibility = "`gone`" / "`invisible`" by xml.

```
 if (!dataList.isEmpty ( )) {
                            //if data is available, don't show the empty text
                           // Empty_View.setVisibility (View.INVISIBLE);
                            progressBar.setVisibility (View.GONE);
                            adapter = new Document_adapter (dataList, getApplicationContext ( ));
                            documentListView.setAdapter (adapter);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ( );

                        } else {
                            Empty_View.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: can you explain, full thing how you are doing ?